# How to show In call status Bar(double height) for Voip Application with green color in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, voip, statusbar, in-call

I am developing an app based on sip calling and I want to send call in background if any one starts call and comes out of application .In that case I want to display call duration on screen .For that that I am using in_call status bar.But the code I have used is setting background color of in_call status bar  to red and I am not getting how  to change its color to green  also  want to show timer on it .As I am using this first time I am not getting how to solve this .Here is my code .Please help if any one can . I am calling this method on **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** method

```
    +(void) startRecording {
    AVAudioSession * audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError * err = nil;
    [audioSession setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: & err];
    if (err) {
        NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [
            [err userInfo] description
        ]);
        return;
    }
    [audioSession setActive: YES error: & err];
    err = nil;
    if (err) {
        NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [
            [err userInfo] description
        ]);
        return;
    }


    NSMutableDictionary * recordSetting = [
        [NSMutableDictionary alloc] init
    ];

    [recordSetting setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatLinearPCM] forKey: AVFormatIDKey];
    [recordSetting setValue: [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0] forKey: AVSampleRateKey];
    [recordSetting setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey: AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

    [recordSetting setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt: 16] forKey: AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
    [recordSetting setValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: NO] forKey: AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
    [recordSetting setValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: NO] forKey: AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];


    NSURL * url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: @"/dev/null"];
    err = nil;
    AVAudioRecorder * recorder = [
        [AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL: url settings: recordSetting error: & err
    ];
    if (!recorder) {
        NSLog(@"recorder: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [
            [err userInfo] description
        ]);
        UIAlertView * alert = [
            [UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
            message: [err localizedDescription]
            delegate: nil
            cancelButtonTitle: @"OK"
            otherButtonTitles: nil
        ];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }

    //prepare to record
    [recorder setDelegate: self];
    [recorder prepareToRecord];
    recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;

    BOOL audioHWAvailable = audioSession.inputIsAvailable;
    if (!audioHWAvailable) {
        UIAlertView * cantRecordAlert = [
            [UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Warning"
            message: @"Audio input hardware not available"
            delegate: nil
            cancelButtonTitle: @"OK"
            otherButtonTitles: nil
        ];
        [cantRecordAlert show];
        return;
    }

    // start recording
    [recorder record]; //recordForDuration:(NSTimeInterval) 40];
}
```

Comment: Did you solved the problem?

Comment: @Vikas Goyal is anyone of you know, how to show green bar on top of application in foreground state.

Comment: @Sega-Zero is anyone of you know, how to show green bar on top of application in foreground state.

Comment: Have a look on my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38738195/1254172